# How to move turtles created in NetLogo on the roads (polyline vectors) loaded from GIS shp?

Tags: gis, netlogo, arcgis

I have Residential Polygons and Infrastructure (Schools, Hospitals, etc.) Polygons, and Road Polylines from GIS, loaded in NetLogo. As per the respective populations of residential polygons, I have created turtles in them. Now I want those turtles to move from Residential to Infrastructure (say school). A turtle should travel less than 800 metres, and choose the paths with least impedance (Total impedance = ImpFacRoad1*DistanceTravelledRoad1 + ImpFacRoad2*DistanceTravelledRoad2...), and up to the capacity of the school (say 10000 persons).

I have been able to accomplish the previous steps like loading shps and adding population turtles to residential patches.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2U5X.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0HVk.png)

The code is relevant to previous steps and is not linked to my exact question. Shall share anyway.

```
extensions [gis]

globals [infra-dataset
    rd-dataset
    node-dataset
    res-dataset]



 to setup
    ca
    set infra-dataset gis:load-dataset "C://Users//Riya//Desktop//NT//infra.shp"
    set rd-dataset gis:load-dataset "C://Users//Riya//Desktop//NT//rd.shp"
    set res-dataset gis:load-dataset "C://Users//Riya//Desktop//NT//res.shp"
   gis:set-world-envelope-ds gis:envelope-of lu-dataset
 ;infra
    foreach  gis:feature-list-of infra-dataset
     [[t]->
     if gis:property-value t "fac_head" = "Education" [gis:set-drawing-color red gis:fill t 2.0]
     if gis:property-value t "fac_head" = "Health" [gis:set-drawing-color green gis:fill t 2.0]
     if gis:property-value t "fac_head" = "Safety" [gis:set-drawing-color violet gis:fill t 2.0]
     if gis:property-value t "fac_type" = "Vacant" [gis:set-drawing-color cyan gis:draw t 2.0]
  ]
  ;rd
    foreach  gis:feature-list-of rd-dataset
     [[t]->
     if gis:property-value t "Width" = 18 [gis:set-drawing-color white gis:draw t 1.8]
     if gis:property-value t "Width" = 30 [gis:set-drawing-color white gis:draw t 3.0]
     if gis:property-value t "Width" = 45 [gis:set-drawing-color white gis:draw t 4.5]
  ]
; res
    foreach  gis:feature-list-of res-dataset
     [[t]->
      if gis:property-value t "Density" < 1.04 [gis:set-drawing-color yellow - 2 gis:fill t 2.0]
      if gis:property-value t "Density" > 1.04 and gis:property-value t "Density" < 1.8 [gis:set-drawing-color yellow gis:fill t 2.0]
      if gis:property-value t "Density" > 1.8 [gis:set-drawing-color yellow + 2 gis:fill t 2.0]
  ]
end

to night ; turtles stay in residential patches at night
    foreach gis:feature-list-of res-dataset
     [[t]->
      let pop ( gis:property-value t "Population" ) / 100
      let target-patches ( patches gis:intersecting t ) with [ gis:contained-by? self t ]
      if any? target-patches [
      let avg-turtles round ( pop / count target-patches )
      ask target-patches [
        sprout avg-turtles
  ]
  ]
  ]
    ask turtles [set shape "person"]
    reset-ticks
end
```

How to move turtles created in NetLogo on the roads (polyline vectors) loaded from GIS shp, that too to a specific distance, and prioritizing roads on the basis of least impedance (provided as an attribute to the road shapefile)?
I am expecting that the turtle moves from home to school. If it is able to get in the school, it turns green, but if it doesn't, it'll have to move back home and turn red.

Comment: I was wondering if it could work if somehow my turtles move to the centroid of the infrastructure polygon, and then get sprouted.

Comment: Look in the NetLogo models library (File menu) for the Link-Walking Turtles Example. The general approach you will need is to place a new breed of turtle to mark the transit points and links between those to mark the roads. You may also need the network extension to do some of you impedance calculations.